# Observations of Student-t Distribution with Degrees of Freedom - R

Tags: r, syntax, statistics

So I'm trying to learn R and using a number of resources including a book called "Discovering Statistics using R" and a bunch of other cool eBooks.

I've also been reading a tutorial page about [Student-t Distribution](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/student-t-distribution) and the wiki of [Degree's of Freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28statistics%29).

How can this be implemented in R? For example, simulating say 500 student-t distribution observations with 5 degrees of freedom?

Although I think I get the concept, I'm unsure of the functions/syntax to achieve this in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the function `rt` in package `stats`

From `?rt`:

```
rt(n, df, ncp)
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I envy your R knowledge (: thanks for posting.